# Could not find ApacheJmeter_core.jar

Tags: java, jmeter, java-14

Getting the below response while running jmeter.server Batch file:

```
Could not find ApacheJmeter_core.jar ...
```

[image]

what to do now? I am using Java version-14

Comment: What version of JMeter are you using and instead of sharing the screenshot can you Share the command and logs as a text?

Answer (score 0):

Could not find ApacheJmeter_core.jar ... meaning you haven't started Jmeter master.

But above error is different, in this case Jmeter slave cannot find rmi keystore file at bin folder thus throwing file not found exception for rmi_keystore.jks.

You have to generate rmi_keystore.jks by running create-rmi-keystore.bat for windows (for mac you have to run create-rmi-keystore.sh) then once .jks file is generated then copy it in bin folder of each Jmeter slave.

For more details, you can refer link: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#setup_ssl